# Setting Powershell colors with hex values in profile script

Tags: powershell, colors

I know I can change PowerShell console colors by setting in my profile something like:

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "White"
Clear-Host
```

However in the Powershell Console one can go to the Color tab in Properties and modify the RGB values of the standard 16 ANSI colors manually. Is it possible to do set either hex or RGB values of the standard colors from the profile script? For instance setting I would like to have:

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = "#242424"  # Gray
Clear-Host
```

Comment: Here is an answer that actually works:
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18686048/2292766

Comment: @HannesSchneidermayer The linked solution sets the colors for PowerShell terminals opened via the windows run interface (windows key + r). It doesn't work for PowerShell started via the start menu, e.g., via windows key + x. The start menu PowerShell is a shortcut stored under app data. I have no idea how to interface with its color settings programmatically.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, but not via the `$Host` object. The color table is stored in the registry.

You would use the same names, but the colors would be different. That's why the default PowerShell console is blue/gray.

Answer (score 9):

The correct way to do this is with the Registry

```sh
cd hkcu:/console
$0 = '%systemroot%_system32_windowspowershell_v1.0_powershell.exe'
ni $0 -f
sp $0 ColorTable00 0x00562401
sp $0 ColorTable07 0x00f0edee
```

With the color being

```
0x00BBGGRR
```

Comment: I found that these settings take effect only after making a change in the properties window. Somehow all these settings are completely ignored running this on say a new computer. You have to make any change at all before new windows will respect these settings as far as my experience goes.

Comment: Can anyone expand on this answer?  What are ColorTable00 and ColorTable07?  How did you arrive at "With the color being 0x00BBGGRR"?

Comment: Should the changes take place as I execute the commands or do I need to start a new window? Reboot the computer?

Comment: 8 years later, you managed to make me feel like an idiot. I had no idea you could `cd` into the registry! Thank you. :D

Answer (score 3):

I doubt that's possible. The $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColour is a System.ConsoleColor enumerator, thus there's only a finite set of colours that you could select.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.consolecolor.aspx

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, you can't. The console API doesn't support custom color. If you do this:

```
$x = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI
$x | gm
```

you'll see that BackgroundColor is of type [System.ConsoleColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that may be looking to custom color the Powershell ISE here is the format.

```
    #Get the list of colors and hex equivalents
     [windows.media.colors] | Get-Member -Static -MemberType property | 
    ForEach-Object { 
    $psISE.Options.ConsolePaneTextBackgroundColor = `
    ([windows.media.colors]::$($_.name)).tostring() 
    "$($_.name) `t $([windows.media.colors]::$($_.name))" 
    }
    
    #Example of how to change the console color in the powershell ISE
    $psISE.Options.ConsolePaneBackgroundColor = '#FF4169E1'  #RoyalBlue
    $psISE.Options.ConsolePaneTextBackgroundColor = '#00FFFFFF'  #Transparent
```

Proper credit belongs to "The scripting Guy", sorry I don't have the link but the code is directly from his website.

Comment: Your code is not working - strange quotes and syntax errors.

Comment: Fixed the slant quotes problem. Seem it happen when you copy/paste from web pages.