# How to set Powershell background color programmatically to RGB Value

Tags: powershell, console

The current selection of 16 colors from Console Colors is not the right choice for me. I would like to use much darker variants of these for the background.

I could definitely set these using the UI and changing the RGB value there.

[image: Selecting Blue and changing value to 65]

For example, I could choose Darkblue and select 65 for Blue in the RGB section(128 is the default). Could some one tell me how to do this programmatically.

Something like:

```
(Get-Host).UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor=DarkBlue
```

But with additional options.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting Powershell colors with hex values in profile script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280402/setting-powershell-colors-with-hex-values-in-profile-script)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This old post by Lee Holmes explains how you can go about changing the color to any value you want. You have to change the registry - http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2008/06/01/powershells-noble-blue/

```
Push-Location 
Set-Location HKCU:\Console 
New-Item ".\%SystemRoot%_system32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe" 
Set-Location ".\%SystemRoot%_system32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe"

New-ItemProperty . ColorTable00 -type DWORD -value 0×00562401 
New-ItemProperty . ColorTable07 -type DWORD -value 0x00f0edee 
New-ItemProperty . FaceName -type STRING -value "Lucida Console" 
New-ItemProperty . FontFamily -type DWORD -value 0×00000036 
New-ItemProperty . FontSize -type DWORD -value 0x000c0000 
New-ItemProperty . FontWeight -type DWORD -value 0×00000190 
New-ItemProperty . HistoryNoDup -type DWORD -value 0×00000000 
New-ItemProperty . QuickEdit -type DWORD -value 0×00000001 
New-ItemProperty . ScreenBufferSize -type DWORD -value 0x0bb80078 
New-ItemProperty . WindowSize -type DWORD -value 0×00320078 
Pop-Location
```

Answer (score 7):

This powershell function mimics the cmd line call: `color b0`

```
function Set-ConsoleColor ($bc, $fc) {
    $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = $bc
    $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = $fc
    Clear-Host
}
Set-ConsoleColor 'cyan' 'black'
```

Console color names can be retrieved with the following code:

```
[Enum]::GetValues([ConsoleColor])
```

Comment: This works until a command is entered. Then it falls back to the old color scheme.

Answer (score 4):

I've added this function to my powershell profile since there is a program that regularly messes up the colors of my shell.

```
$DefaultForeground = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor
$DefaultBackground = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor
function SetColors
{
    Param
    (
        [string]$Foreground = "",
        [string]$Background = ""
    )

    $ValidColors = "black","blue","cyan","darkblue" ,"darkcyan","darkgray",
        "darkgreen","darkmagenta","darkred","darkyellow","gray","green",
        "magenta","red","white","yellow";

    $Foreground = $Foreground.ToLower()
    $Background = $Background.ToLower()

    if ( $Foreground -eq "" )
    {
        $Foreground = $DefaultForeground
    }
    if ( $Background -eq "" )
    {
        $Background = $DefaultBackground
    }

    if ( $ValidColors -contains $Foreground -and
         $ValidColors -contains $Background )
    {
        $a = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI
        $a.ForegroundColor = $Foreground
        $a.BackgroundColor = $Background
    }
    else 
    {
        write-host "Foreground/Background Colors must be one of the following:"
        $ValidColors 
    }
}
set-alias set-colors SetColors
```

Some notes:

*"$DefaultCololrs = (Get-Host).UI.RawUI"* creates more of a pointer-type object than an actual copy of the object.  This means that if you later set a different variable equal to *"(Get-Host).UI.RawUI"*, and change things, $DefaultColors will also change (which is why I've made sure to copy them here as strings).

I tried setting other colors (using hex codes) with very little luck, though I did find [Setting Powershell colors with hex values in profile script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280402/setting-powershell-colors-with-hex-values-in-profile-script) (I just haven't tried it yet, since I'm not particularly fond of mucking about in the registry, and the default list of colors seemed rather sufficient).

I also found this document: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff406264.aspx, which I may have to use later to figure out how to modify my "grep" command (currently I have it aliased to select-string)