# Powershell >6.0... command line background color with ANSI sequences (PSReadLine) ?how?

Tags: powershell, command-line, colors, psreadline

In PowerShell >6.0 I can change the command line FOREGROUND colors with:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{ Keyword="#0FAFE0"; Variable="#987ABC" }+
```

but how do I change the BACKGROUND colors with RGB??? (#RRGGBB)
i can see some examples with ASCII console sequences
but none with the RGB format

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set Powershell background color programmatically to RGB Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685772/how-to-set-powershell-background-color-programmatically-to-rgb-value)

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can?  SelectionColor uses the ansi escape code for black on white:  "`e[30;47m" (ps 7 for the `e). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Colors

How about this from that wikipeda page:

> ESC[ 38;2;⟨r⟩;⟨g⟩;⟨b⟩ m -- choose RGB foreground color
>
> ESC[ 48;2;⟨r⟩;⟨g⟩;⟨b⟩ m -- choose RGB background color

Red foreground (255 0 0) blue (0 0 255) background.

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{ variable = "`e[38;2;255;0;0m" + # fg
                                           "`e[48;2;0;0;255m" } # bg
```

In ps5 you have to say $([char]0x1b) instead of `e.

```
$e = [char]0x1b
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{ variable = "$e[38;2;255;0;0m" + # fg
                                           "$e[48;2;0;0;255m" } # bg
```

Comment: That's exactly that... meanwhile I read the very interesting Wikipedia article about the history of ANSI control sequences... and I recommend it -> "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code"

Comment: I'm not clear on that `Select` part. Is that a PS command or where does it come from?

Comment: @KonradViltersten That's just a quote from the wikipedia docs.

Comment: Ah. hahaha. so silly of me. In the markdown, it appeared colored as if it was a keyword, or something. I tried it and googled it but couldn't find anything on it. The site thought probably that you were writing a SQL statement or something.