# Set the text color in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to customize the terminal window of my PS (5.1.18362.752). Using the Properties menu and Colors tab, I have set the main background and the printed text as I wish. The colors of errors and warnings are set using a script (following [this blog](https://beebom.com/how-change-powershell-color-scheme-windows-10/)).

```
$hostGui = $Host.UI.RawUI
$colors = $Host.PrivateData

$hostGui.WindowTitle = "Powerify!"
$hostGui.backgroundcolor = "magenta"
$hostGui.foregroundcolor = "green"

$colors.verbosebackgroundcolor = "magenta"
$colors.verboseforegroundcolor = "green"
$colors.warningbackgroundcolor = "magenta"
$colors.warningforegroundcolor = "green"
$colors.ErrorBackgroundColor = "magenta"
$colors.ErrorForegroundColor = "green"
```

Further, I also manipulate the prompt's color using the following script (following [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1259916/161760) and coloring strategy [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#text-formatting)).

```
function prompt {
  $foreRgb = "15;15;15"
  $backRgb = "240;240;240"
  $style = [char]27 + "[38;2;" + $foreRgb + ";48;2;" + $backRgb + "m"
  ...
  $prompt = $style + $whatever + "> "
  Write-Host $prompt -nonewline
  return " "
}
```

All the above **works**, as far I can tell from the screen. However, what I don't get to work is the actual text that the user types in after the prompt, i.e. the command itself. The first word typed in is yellow and the following ones are bright green (or dark green if it's a string), while CTRL+C is displayed in red. While I understand that it's the formatting for the main command and the parameters.

I haven't found any information on how to control those colors, despite it being suggested that it's supposed to be possible (according to [this blog](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/new-experimental-console-features/)).

Most preferably, I'd like to set them from the script but a menu setting will do too. Worst case, I can also live with a registry hack but that's the last resort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want is [Set-PSReadLineOption](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/psreadline/set-psreadlineoption?view=powershell-7)? It specifies the colors of the commands that you type in the prompt.

> The Set-PSReadLineOption cmdlet customizes the behavior of the PSReadLine module when you're editing the command line.

You can set it via script or put it in your [$profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_profiles?view=powershell-7#the-profile-variable).

As an example, here's my "theme":

```
Set-PSReadlineOption -Colors @{
    Type = "DarkCyan"
    Member = "Gray"
    String = "DarkGray"
    Number = "Yellow"
    Comment = "DarkGreen"
    Command = "Cyan"
    Keyword = "Cyan"
    Operator = "Gray"
    Variable = "Magenta"
    Parameter = "Gray"
}
```

Comment: I'll give it a whack tomorrow. I just wanted to express a certain discontent that a single UI, the terminal window, requires three different approaches to be customized. That is not my favorite part of PowerShell experience.

Comment: This was a great answer and even better reference link. I got to set options I haven't thought to be possible. Thanks! However, I wonder if you have a suggestion on setting the other properties (not related to *read line options*) I described in my question. The colors of the console as such, that is. I'd love to set them from my script all together.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Glad I could help. I am not sure what other colors you mean. But either way, I don't have any experience with that, sorry.

Comment: Actually, you might have experience of that and it's only me explaining it poorly. How would you set the color of the printout for e.g. *dir* in the console? I did that using the settings in the GUI but it'd be great to set them from script, somehow. As, for instance, the background color and the color of the prompt. Stuff like that. Bu if you don't know that one, it's still great and thanks.

Comment: @KonradViltersten https://stackoverflow.com/a/28798070/2060966

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
Set-PSReadLineOption -Colors @{
    "Parameter"="#ff81f7"
    "Command"="Blue"
    "Error"=[ConsoleColor]::DarkRed
}
```

Source: This [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/1368556/926959) answer