# Windows 10 Ping Script and Color output

Tags: powershell, ping

I run a maintenance routine every month that pings about 15 devices. I simply want to run a command script that does the following.

- Calls a txt file (that I have populated with 15 or so IP addresses)
- Opens 15 separate command windows and runs a continuous PING (ie Start cmd ping 10.1.1.5 /t)
- Cascades all of the 15 separate windows
- Here is where the issue is... If the device reply's back to the ping, I want the screen output to have Black txt and a Green background to show a positive response. If the device times out, then I want the screen output to have black txt and a Red background to signify and issue.

Answer (score 0):

It took a bit of tinkering (because I was not familiar with power shell), but here is the result.

I have 3 separate files:

1. A file with all the IP address to ping. (server_ip_addresses.txt)
2. A ping script that pings each IP address in a loop. (ping_window.ps1)
3. A main script that reads the IP address file and starts up the ping scrips in a separate window. (shell.ps1)

## source files:

Place them all in the same directory.

### server_ip_addresses.txt

On each line define 1 IP address e.g:

```
8.8.8.8
1.1.1.1
172.16.0.1
```

(1.DNS google, 2.DNS cloudflare, 3. a private IP address that is not routable in my network)

### ping_window.ps1

```
# function to color the BackGround and ForeGround of the shell
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18685772/how-to-set-powershell-background-color-programmatically-to-rgb-value
function Set-ConsoleColor ($bc, $fc) {
    $Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = $bc
    $Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = $fc
    Clear-Host
}

$loop_count = 0
while($true) {
    $loop_count = $loop_count + 1
    $Host.UI.RawUI.WindowTitle = "ping $Args --- loop: $loop_count"
    
    # execute ping
    Write-Output "$Args"
    $job = ping $Args
    
    # check if we have an error message
    if($job -match "Destination host unreachable") {
        Set-ConsoleColor "red" "black"
    } elseif($job -match "TTL Expired in Transit") {
        Set-ConsoleColor "red" "black"
    } elseif($job -match "Request Timed Out") {
        Set-ConsoleColor "red" "black"
    } elseif($job -match "Unknown Host") {
        Set-ConsoleColor "red" "black"
    } else {
        Set-ConsoleColor "green" "black"
    }
    
    Write-Output "Result: $job"
}
```

### shell.ps1

```
# run with: "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\shell.ps1"

Write-Output $Args[0]

$stream_reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader{server_ip_addresses.txt}
$line_number = 1
while (($current_line =$stream_reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null)
{
    Invoke-Expression 'cmd /c start powershell -NoExit .\ping_window.ps1 $current_line'
    $line_number++
}
```

## execution and output

Because I did not run as administrator, I had to bypass the 'execution policy':

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\shell.ps1
```

For each IP address in server_ip_addresses.txt, a new power shell window is created. (I believe they are cascaded by default)

Instead of running it continuously with the ping -t flag, we just send 4 pings. Then we read the output, color the shell appropriately and ping again. With the loop counter in the window title, you can keep track of how many times the ping command has been executed.

To check if we have an error message (and color the shell background red), the script tries to match the following substrings:

- "Destination host unreachable"
- "TTL Expired in Transit"
- "Request Timed Out"
- "Unknown Host"

If none of the messages are found, the background is set to green.
It could also be adapted to use different background colors and/or font colors. Just change the parameters of `Set-ConsoleColor` in ping_window.ps1

With the current server_ip_addresses.txt I get this output:
[image]

To stop execution, I think you have to stop the script first and then close the windows. Otherwise they keep running in the background.