# Programmatically change PowerShell's 16 default console colours

Tags: powershell, colors, customization

PowerShell improves on the (frankly) fugly Windows Console colour scheme by assigning a bluish value to one of its 16 console colours ( - the one known as DarkMagenta for some reason - ), and uses this as the default screen background.

I want to programmatically change each of the 16 colours to a custom colour scheme. In my PowerShell profile, for example.

I've found explanations on how to change which one of the ConsoleHost's 16 colours gets assigned to different kinds of text, but what I want is to actually change each of the ConsoleHost's 16 colours to a different hex value. (For myself only, not for other users, or other consoles, such as `cmd.exe`.)

Of course this can be done by right-clicking the menu bar and manually adjusting the "Properties" or "Default" settings, but this gets very quickly tiring. And I cannot locate where these settings get persisted.

(I have already searched the registry and `C:\Users\<current_user>\AppData`, and found nothing, except for the `ColorTable##` properties under `HKCU:\Console`, whose scope is obviously broader than the PowerShell console settings.)

If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The console colors are defined in multiple places:

- **Global/Default**: `HKCU:\Console`. This applies to all `conhost.exe`-applications including `cmd.exe` and `powershell.exe`.
- **Per process:** `HKCU:\Console\<PROCESS_PATH_WITH_UNDESCORE>` for process-specific changes. Ex. `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console\%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe` is defined and has modified `ColorTable05` and `ColorTable06`.
- **Per shortcut:** Inside the shortcut (.lnk). This is hard to modify programmatically, would probably require P\Invoke.

You can modify the process-level values with PS using:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path "HKCU:\Console\%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe" -Name ColorTable04 -Value 5645313
```

Be aware that to see the values of the process-level you need start PS using run, windows explorer etc. If you use one of the shortcuts, then the shortcut's values will be used. So it might be easier to modify the shortcut and keep a copy of it for new setups.

Each "ColorTable" has a name hardcoded in the [System.ConsoleColor-enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolecolor(v=vs.110).aspx), so it's just "random" that they used the one called DarkMagneta. Probably because it's a unique color that isn't used that much.

Comment: Correct, the per process approach is discussed in the link at the bottom of my answer. The OP mentions he has been through all these links already, but yet after 2.5 days still has not solved the problem. Unclear why, since these approaches work for everyone else...

Comment: What I needed was an authoritative source explaining the above. All I could find were 'tips and tricks' that didn't explain the underlying system logic. Is there a book, standard, or documentation source I could read that explains the above? In any case, thanks Frode and Kory!

Comment: This one helped me today, thank you! However cumbersome, I used these to transfer the color profile I had from one machine to another. I want to add that the Power Shell you invoke from the `windows + x` menu actually initiates a shortcut, which is located at: `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Windows PowerShell`

Comment: Is there a way to read the current effective value of each "ColorTable" value, and (ideally) its source?

Comment: Also: Is there a way to tell what process key to use, since there appears to be some reverse environment variable interpolation in play?

Comment: @brianary If it's possible, it will most likely require some P\Invoke to get the values. Maybe you can borrow some P\Invoke-parts from  https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSConsoleTheme/0.1.1/Content/Private%5CSet-ColorPalette.ps1 and modify it to read the bufferinfo, get the colorref.toString() values and parse them to Color-objects. As for the process-part, your speaking 10 levels above my development knowledge :-)

Comment: @FrodeF. Thanks, I'll have to check. For the other part, I'm just wondering how you get from the full, physical path (starting with _C:\Windows_) to the registry location that starts with _%SystemRoot%_, for a process other than _powershell.exe_, like maybe something under _C:\Program Files_. Maybe the same process invoke data would include the original startup path, before the environment variables are substituted in.

Comment: Isn't it just the full path with \ replaced with _? `%programfiles%_MyApp1_ConsoleApp.exe`

Answer (score 5):

I searched for "change powershell console color" and found tons of examples.

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

[How can I set the PowerShell console background color](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4b43f071-abf5-4a65-9048-82d474473a8e/how-can-i-set-the-powershell-console-background-color-not-the-text-background-color?forum=winserverpowershell)

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor = ($bckgrnd = 'DarkBlue')
$Host.UI.RawUI.ForegroundColor = 'White'
$Host.PrivateData.ErrorForegroundColor = 'Red'
$Host.PrivateData.ErrorBackgroundColor = $bckgrnd
$Host.PrivateData.WarningForegroundColor = 'Magenta'
$Host.PrivateData.WarningBackgroundColor = $bckgrnd
$Host.PrivateData.DebugForegroundColor = 'Yellow'
$Host.PrivateData.DebugBackgroundColor = $bckgrnd
$Host.PrivateData.VerboseForegroundColor = 'Green'
$Host.PrivateData.VerboseBackgroundColor = $bckgrnd
$Host.PrivateData.ProgressForegroundColor = 'Cyan'
$Host.PrivateData.ProgressBackgroundColor = $bckgrnd
Clear-Host
```

There is also another discussion on the topic at:

[Setting Powershell colors with hex values in profile script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280402/setting-powershell-colors-with-hex-values-in-profile-script)

Comment: I'd actually come across all of those materials in my 2.5 days of searching on the topic. Forget about the value of `$Host.UI.RawUI.BackgroundColor`. It's the value of `DarkBlue` that I want to change. This is easily done by right-clicking the menu bar, but where are these customizations saved? Not in the registry key that Lee Holmes references, because it isn't there on my system.

Comment: Did you try to create the key if it did not exist to get this working per the last link in my answer for the existing answer on SO for this similar question?

Answer (score 2):

I have made a utility for Windows console colors called [Concfg](https://github.com/lukesampson/concfg).

It can import colours from JSON preset files, and takes care of removing the overrides from the registry and .lnk files.