# Using "Run with Powershell" to invoke a script won't show a DarkMagenta background

Tags: powershell

I have the following script in a ps1 file:

```
Write-Host "Hello world" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor DarkMagenta
```

If I open a Powershell window myself, and invoke the script (by just running *.\myscript.ps1*), then I get a nice dark magenta background. However, if I right-click on the ps1 file and select "Run with Powershell", I don't get a dark magenta background. Other background colors work fine though.

What is going on and how can I make them behave in the same way?

Comment: This is on Windows Server 2016. I can find some articles that talk about this, but I haven't got their solutions to work: http://www.leeholmes.com/blog/2008/06/01/powershells-noble-blue/

Comment: Have you seen: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36116326/programmatically-change-powershells-16-default-console-colours/36117276#36117276?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 16 console colors are determined by `ColorTable00` .. `ColorTable15` in the registry under HKCU:console or any other shortcut used to start an app.

This slightly reworked table shows the normal entries and the two differing entries 05 and 06 for powershell.

```
                                             Blue Green Red
> REG QUERY "hkcu\console" |find /I "ColorTable"
    ColorTable00    REG_DWORD    0x000000       0    0    0 
    ColorTable01    REG_DWORD    0x800000     128    0    0
    ColorTable02    REG_DWORD    0x008000       0  128    0
    ColorTable03    REG_DWORD    0x808000     128  128    0
    ColorTable04    REG_DWORD    0x000080       0    0  128
    ColorTable05    REG_DWORD    0x800080     128    0  128
    ColorTable06    REG_DWORD    0x008080       0  128  128
    ColorTable07    REG_DWORD    0xc0c0c0     192  192  192
    ColorTable08    REG_DWORD    0x808080     128  128  128
    ColorTable09    REG_DWORD    0xff0000     255    0    0
    ColorTable10    REG_DWORD    0x00ff00       0  255    0
    ColorTable11    REG_DWORD    0xffff00     255  255    0
    ColorTable12    REG_DWORD    0x0000ff       0    0  255
    ColorTable13    REG_DWORD    0xff00ff     255    0  255
    ColorTable14    REG_DWORD    0x00ffff       0  255  255
    ColorTable15    REG_DWORD    0xffffff     255  255  255
                                             Blue Green Red
HKCU\console\%SystemRoot%_System32_WindowsPowerShell_v1.0_powershell.exe
    ColorTable05    REG_DWORD    0x562401       1   86   36   
    ColorTable06    REG_DWORD    0xf0edee     238  237  240
```