# Missing powershell colors in properties?

Tags: powershell

I was playing around with my powershell colors and I noticed that a bunch of colors had just gone missing and were replaced with black. Now whenever I type in an incorrect command in powershell I get the error message, but it's just replaced with all blank. Anyway I can get back the colors and fix the error message? Here are links to images.[This shows the missing colors in properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPSxu.jpg)

[This one shows the black error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vTbE.jpg)

Comment: Take a Look at your registry (HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console) as described here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36116326/programmatically-change-powershells-16-default-console-colours

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to reset them.  But I can give you the values I have, which should be the defaults.

Select "Screen Background" since we know it is the blue, second from the left, and can easily return to that.

Now select the far left color cell, and starting from there, the RGB values are:

```
0,0,0
0,0,128
0,128,0
0,128,128
128,0,0
1,36,86
238,237,240
192,192,192
128,128,128
0,0,255
0,255,0
0,255,255
255,0,0
255,0,255
255,255,0
255,255,255
```

Next, set the text and background colors.

Select "Screen Text" and set it to the 7th cell, with value 238,237,240.

Select "Screen Background" and set it to the 2nd cell, with value 0,0,128.

Select "Popup Text" and set it to the 4th cell, with value 0,128,128

Select "Popup Background" and set it to the 16th cell (far right), with value 255,255,255.